# Problem adding multiple author in elsarticle template

Tags: elsarticle, addresses

Hello I'm new writing an article using elsarticle.cls.
I met some problem to add multi address.
When I code like this

```
\documentclass[5p,twocolumn, times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyphens]{xurl}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}
\author[1,2]{Byeoungju Lee}
\author[1, 3]{Kwangnam Yu}
\author[4]{Jiwon Jeon}

\author[1]{E. J. Choi\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{echoi@uos.ac.kr}

\address[1]{Department of Physics, University of Seoul, Seoul 130-743, Korea}
\address[2]{Department of Smart City, University of Seoul, Seoul 130-743, Korea}
\address[3]{SK Siltron Inc., 132-11, 3gongdan 3-ro, Gumi-si, Gyeongsangbuk-do 39400, South 
 Korea}
\address[4]{NSRI(Natural Science Research Institute), University of Seoul,  Seoul 130-743, 
 Korea}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}
article body
\end{document}
```

And I compiled it. The result is
[image]

The address 3 is written on Kwangnam Yu as 1, not c.
Why address is not written as c?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Just remove the space at `\author[1,3]{Kwangnam Yu}`.

Comment: @dexteritas Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! I copied your code in overleaf and deleted the space for `\author[1,3]{Kwangnam Yu}` between the 1 and 3 and it gives the address as c.

[image]

```
\documentclass[5p,twocolumn, times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyphens]{xurl}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}
\author[1,2]{Byeoungju Lee}
\author[1,3]{Kwangnam Yu}
\author[4]{Jiwon Jeon}

\author[1]{E. J. Choi\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{echoi@uos.ac.kr}

\address[1]{Department of Physics, University of Seoul, Seoul 130-743, Korea}
\address[2]{Department of Smart City, University of Seoul, Seoul 130-743, Korea}
\address[3]{SK Siltron Inc., 132-11, 3gongdan 3-ro, Gumi-si, Gyeongsangbuk-do 39400, South 
 Korea}
\address[4]{NSRI(Natural Science Research Institute), University of Seoul,  Seoul 130-743, 
 Korea}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}
article body
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I see  @dexteritas already solved this!